# 'text' is not a valid value for the enum 'FieldType'

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

**Error**

> Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: 'text' is not a valid value for the enum 'FieldType' faultcode=soapenv:Client

**Code**

```
List<MetadataService.Metadata> customfieldList = new List<MetadataService.Metadata>(); 

           for(integer i=1;i<stringCSVRecords.size();i++){
               MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();   

                string[] splitRecords = stringCSVRecords[i].split(',');
                customField.fullName  = splitRecords[0]+'__c.'+splitRecords[1]+'__c';
                System.debug('Custom Field Full Name'+' '+customField.fullName);
                customField.label     = splitRecords[1];
                customField.type_x    = splitRecords[2];    // text is provided in the csv file and retrieve here
                customField.length    = 42;

                customfieldList.add(customField);
            }
          /* custom Fields are finally created by the same method createMetadat Here */
             List<MetadataService.SaveResult> fieldsCreated = service.createMetadata(customfieldList);
```

Answer (score 5):

The values of the `FieldType` element of a `CustomField` are case sensitive. The legal values are documented in [Metadata Field Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm#meta_type_fieldtype), under `FieldType`.

Your CSV file needs to specify the type `Text`, not `text`. You can demonstrate this for yourself by pulling the metadata down for an object containing a text field and changing its type to `text` - you'll get the same error if you try to deploy that metadata.